# Multiple python 2.7 versions on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

How can I have different 2.7.x versions in parallel on Windows? The installer overwrites older versions even if installed into a different directory.

Background:

I'd like to have more than one version of CPython 2.7 installed on a Windows machine for continuous integration purposes. I can do that without problems on Linux and OSX already.

Having different 2.x and 3.x versions in parallel works fine, but due to the longlivety of Python 2.7 (initial release in 2010) the 2.7.x versions aren't all that compatible among each other, and users don't update all that frequently.

Comment: Virtual environment maybe? And why do you need multiple 2.x?

Comment: What incompatibilities are you finding between 2.7.x versions?  There should be very little difference between those.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Bugs and bug fixes. `inspect.getsource()` for example requires workarounds in earlier versions that, unfortunately, are still in use on some of my user's boxes. Depending on your project, it can be quite easy to break compatibiliy with ealier 2.7.x versions.

Comment: You could look at [portable python](http://portablepython.com/).

Comment: BrenBarn, can you make that into an answer? I just gave it a try and it seems to be working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching I think it is safe to say that BrenBarn's comment answers it best:

[Portable Python](http://portablepython.com) versions can be installed in parallel even if they have the same first two digits. The drawbacks are that the available versions lack behind quite a bit and there are only available in 32-bit (which makes perfect sense, they are made for portability after all).

Answer (score -1):

I use the conda by Continuum Analytics to easily switch between Python versions

http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda